# Smooth animation for a view

Tags: java, android, animation, android-viewpager

I'm making an animation for `page` in a `ViewPager` using the method `transformPage` :

**The problem** : i need to fix a value for `scale` (between 0.8 => 1, i mean: 0.81, 0.82, 0.83......0.89,0.90,...0.99 ) variable depending on the position (from 0.5 to 1) to get smooth animation from small to big.

```
        else if (position >= 0.5F && position <= 1F) {                       

                ...
                scale = ??;

                ViewCompat.setScaleX(page, scale);
                ViewCompat.setScaleY(page, 0.85F);
        }
```

what i tried so far :

```
scale = (float) (0.8 + ((10*position)/100));  ==> not correct
```

also i tried multiple `else if`'s, like:

```
else if (position >= 0.5F && position <= 0.625F) { 
       scale = .97
}

else if (position >= 0.625F && position <= 0.75F) { 
       scale = .9
}

else if (position >= 0.75F && position <= 0.875F) {  
       scale = .85
}

else if (position >= 0.875F && position <= 1.0F) {  
       scale = .80
}
```

==> the result is so laggy.

please help, Thank you

-- **Update**: using @RadekJ answer i get reverse result: from 1 to 0.8:

[image]

Comment: yes this is correct

Comment: And why scaleY is 0.85F constant. And just for my knowledge why are you writing ViewCompat.setScale. You can also write page.setScaleY?

Comment: i just need setScaleX, the view take only 85% of the screen in the Y scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing it always this way:

```
float progressStart = 0.5f
float progressEnd = 1f;
float progressDelta = progressEnd - progressStart;

float progress = (position - progressStart)/progressDelta;
if(progress>1)progress=1;
if(progress<0)progress=0;

float endValue = 1f;
float startValue = 0.8f;

float delta = endValue - startValue;
float currentScale = startValue + delta*progress;

ViewCompat.setScaleX(page, currentScale);
```

Comment: i need the reverse, i'm getting from 1 to 0.8

Comment: please check my question for a result picture

Comment: then add `progress = 1-progress` before the line where `currentScale` is calculated

Comment: You welcome! You can simply switch `endValue` with `startValue` to make it more readable ;)

Comment: hi please help me if you can with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245228/animation-in-a-vertical-viewpager   thank you