# Animation in a vertical ViewPager

Tags: java, android, animation, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I need to make this animation in a vertical `ViewPager` :

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuE-4jjnp3g

this what i tried so far :

```
   viewPager = (VerticalViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

   viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

            if (position >= 0.5F && position <= 1F) {

                float progressStart = 0.5f;
                float progressEnd = 1f;
                float progressDelta = progressEnd - progressStart;

                float progress = (position - progressStart)/progressDelta;
                if(progress>1)progress=1;
                if(progress<0)progress=0;

                float endValue = 1f;
                float startValue = 0.8f;

                float delta = endValue - startValue;

                progress = 1-progress;
                float currentScale = startValue + delta*progress;

                ViewCompat.setPivotY(page,0);
                ViewCompat.setScaleX(page, currentScale);
                ViewCompat.setScaleY(page, 0.9F);
                ViewCompat.setTranslationY(page, 0);

            } else {
                ViewCompat.setScaleX(page, 1.0F); //- width
                ViewCompat.setScaleY(page, 0.9F); //- height
            }

        }
    });
```

this is the result:

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9W2lCKP-_s

I'm using a Copy of original ViewPager with vertical orientation, to see the code : https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager/blob/master/infinitecycleviewpager/src/main/java/com/gigamole/infinitecycleviewpager/VerticalViewPager.java

Obviously its not even close, i need to have a preview of the next page and make the two pages closer .

[image]

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: what `VerticalViewPager` are you using?

Comment: hi, please check it here: https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager/blob/master/infinitecycleviewpager/src/main/java/com/gigamole/infinitecycleviewpager/VerticalViewPager.java its a Copy of original ViewPager with vertical orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*i need to have a preview of the next page*

you have to add

```
        android:paddingBottom="200dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
```

to your `<com.gigamole.infinitecycleviewpager.VerticalViewPager`in layout

in your java code put it, of course you should tweak `startTranslation` and `startValue` and `paddingBottom` in your layout

```
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
            ViewCompat.setPivotY(page,0);
            ViewCompat.setPivotX(page,page.getWidth()/2);
            float endTranslation = 0f;
            float startTranslation  = -400f;
            float deltaTranslation = endTranslation - startTranslation;

            float endScale = 1f;
            float startScale = 0.8f;
            float deltaScale = endScale - startScale;
            
            float progressStart = 0.5f;
            float progressEnd = 1f;
            float progressDelta = progressEnd - progressStart;

            float progress = (position - progressStart)/progressDelta;
            if(progress>1)progress=1;
            if(progress<0)progress=0;

            progress = 1-progress;
            
            float currentScale = startScale + deltaScale*progress;
            ViewCompat.setScaleX(page, currentScale);
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(page, currentScale);

            float currentTranslation = startTranslation + deltaTranslation*progress;
            ViewCompat.setTranslationY(page, currentTranslation);
        }
```

Comment: its not like the desired animation, the main page not above the next Page

Comment: oh, you are closer, the next page still not OK, please wait i'll upload a video

Comment: set ` viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); ` and tweak values as I said

Comment: still need some tweaking in my part, Thank you.

Comment: hi @RadekJ , after testing on a samsung with api 19, the next page is not centered and above the "main page"

Comment: please check t here :https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-YVBU8iHvqC8/WS1sCu3ky1I/AAAAAAAAUp0/Xit_Cfaz0HgW4XWY2zjLa6noTbW-vG6lACLcB/w1060-h1510-p-rw/IMG_20170530_125105.jpg

Comment: updated my answer, you hawe to set `true` while you are adding `viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer...` and add line `ViewCompat.setPivotX(page,page.getWidth()/2);` in `transformPage` and you can delete this line `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(page, (currentTranslation));` as it is reverse ordered while we are adding page transformer with true (`reverseDrawingOrder`) arguemnt

Comment: hi again, can you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371207/hide-actionbar-on-swipe-vertical-viewpager  Thank you