# hide actionBar on Swipe vertical viewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to hide My ActionBar/toolbar on Swipe using a vertical ViewPager, this is my `MainActivity` XML:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/view_toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/view_home" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/view_left_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I added to my toolbar : `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

i have only Blank page in my Fragment, the `ViewPager` not visible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:background="@color/greeen_theme"
android:clipToPadding="false"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="@color/light_theme_color_read"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/refreshListBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_refresh_list_button_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<com.axample.android.view.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.axample.android.adapter.vertical.VerticalViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pager_padd_botom"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</com.axample.android.view.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWknAZFs6RA

Please Help!!

**Update  :** my `view_left_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:background="@color/black_main"
         tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

<include layout="@layout/view_drawer_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

my `SwipeRefreshLayout`: https://github.com/FredJul/Flym/blob/master/Flym/src/main/java/net/fred/feedex/view/SwipeRefreshLayout.java

Comment: add this to toolbar app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

Comment: Thank you, Now after i scroll the Actionbar hides, but still blank screen, i will add my fragment code.

Comment: Once remove android:visibility="gone" from button and check or add some background color to check whether it is working or not

Comment: i did that, the only visible part is the`NestedScrollView`, the RelativeLayout with all other elements not showing

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: done @MinnuKaAnae

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150397/discussion-between-minnukaanae-and-mounir-elfassi).

Comment: Hi, post your SwipeRefreshLayout class file

Comment: and also post view_left_drawer.xml

Comment: hi, i updated my post..

Comment: I have posted the solution below, try It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem with SwipeRefreshLayout, It should be on top of NestedScrollView Layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   </<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sample.MainActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/refreshListBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/flat_selector"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Add Your ViewPager Instead of TextView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/refreshListBtn"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: its not working still empty fragment, just like the video in my question

Comment: the problem is not in `SwipeRefreshLayout ` i remove it completely, and still the same

Comment: hi, sorry for being late.. my `VerticalViewPager` is the one is not visible

Comment: the other widget are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use this piece of code (see below). But this is prepared for another type of layout. You can try to adapt it to your layout.

```
 public static class ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener implements MyNestedScrollView.ScrollViewListener{

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private State state;
    private float toolbarElevation;

    public ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener(Toolbar toolbar, float toolbarElevation) {
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
        this.state = new State();
        this.toolbarElevation = toolbarElevation;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void toolbarSetElevation(float elevation) {
        if (AndroidUtils.isLollipop()) {
            toolbar.setElevation(elevation == 0 ? 1 : toolbarElevation);
        }
    }

    private void toolbarAnimateShow(final int verticalOffset) {
        toolbar.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                .setDuration(180)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        toolbarSetElevation(verticalOffset == 0 ? 1 : toolbarElevation);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void toolbarAnimateHide() {
        toolbar.animate()
                .translationY(-toolbar.getHeight())
                .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                .setDuration(180)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        toolbarSetElevation(1);
                    }
                });
    }




    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(State state) {
        this.state.verticalOffset = state.verticalOffset;
        this.state.scrollingOffset = state.scrollingOffset;
        if (AndroidUtils.isLollipop()) {
            toolbar.setElevation(state.elevation);
            toolbar.setTranslationY(state.translationY);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public State onSaveInstanceState() {
        state.translationY = toolbar.getTranslationY();
        if (AndroidUtils.isLollipop()) {
            state.elevation = toolbar.getElevation();
        }
        return state;
    }



    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(MyNestedScrollView v, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
        int dy = y-oldy;
        Log.d("dy", ""+dy);
        state.verticalOffset = v.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
        state.scrollingOffset = dy;
        int toolbarYOffset = (int) (dy - toolbar.getTranslationY());
        toolbar.animate().cancel();
        if (state.scrollingOffset > 0) {
            if (toolbarYOffset < toolbar.getHeight()) {
                if (state.verticalOffset > toolbar.getHeight()) {
                    toolbarSetElevation(toolbarElevation);
                }
                toolbar.setTranslationY(state.translationY = -toolbarYOffset);
            } else {
                toolbarSetElevation(1);
                toolbar.setTranslationY(state.translationY = -toolbar.getHeight());
            }
        } else if (state.scrollingOffset < 0) {
            if (toolbarYOffset < 0) {
                if (state.verticalOffset <= 0) {
                    toolbarSetElevation(1);
                }
                toolbar.setTranslationY(state.translationY = 0);
            } else {
                if (state.verticalOffset > toolbar.getHeight()) {
                    toolbarSetElevation(toolbarElevation);
                }
                toolbar.setTranslationY(state.translationY = -toolbarYOffset);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndScroll() {
        if (state.scrollingOffset > 0) {
            if (state.verticalOffset > toolbar.getHeight()) {
                toolbarAnimateHide();
            } else {
                toolbarAnimateShow(state.verticalOffset);
            }
        } else if (state.scrollingOffset < 0) {
            if (toolbar.getTranslationY() < toolbar.getHeight() * -0.6 && state.verticalOffset > toolbar.getHeight()) {
                toolbarAnimateHide();
            } else {
                toolbarAnimateShow(state.verticalOffset);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Parcelable RecyclerView/Toolbar state for simpler saving/restoring its current state.
     */
    public static final class State implements Parcelable {
        public static Creator<State> CREATOR = new Creator<State>() {
            public State createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
                return new State(parcel);
            }

            public State[] newArray(int size) {
                return new State[size];
            }
        };

        // Keeps track of the overall vertical offset in the list
        private int verticalOffset;
        // Determines the scroll UP/DOWN offset
        private int scrollingOffset;
        // Toolbar values
        private float translationY;
        private float elevation;

        State() {
        }

        State(Parcel parcel) {
            this.verticalOffset = parcel.readInt();
            this.scrollingOffset = parcel.readInt();
            this.translationY = parcel.readFloat();
            this.elevation = parcel.readFloat();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
            parcel.writeInt(verticalOffset);
            parcel.writeInt(scrollingOffset);
            parcel.writeFloat(translationY);
            parcel.writeFloat(elevation);
        }
    }
}
```